# How is a Segment different from Marketing List? What is their purpose?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

How is a Segment (Dynamics for Marketing) different from Marketing List (Dynamics for Sales)?

Is Marketing List for Campaign same as Segment for Customer Journey?

Are their purpose any different Marketing List for Campaign and Segment for Customer Journey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important differences:

- You can always add members to/remove members from a marketing list, while you can't modify static segment once it is live
- Marketing list "live" inside CDS (SQL) - i.e. it is subject to SDK limitation like any other entity and performance implications
- Segments "live" in cloud, so they're not subject to SDK limitation (i.e. way better performance, no issues when running big campaign)
- Marketing list can be used for contacts subscription/unsubscription while segments can't
- Segments can be used to process both interactions (i.e. things like clicking an email link, submitting a form, or registering for an event) and profiles, while marketing list can process just profiles

Over all I understand your confusion - its just a matter of providing static segment similar capabilities marketing list have (i.e. subscription/unsubscription).
You can post it as an idea here: https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/list/?forum=dfa5b83d-9e4c-e811-a956-000d3a1bef07

Disclaimer: I work in Microsoft Dynamics Marketing as a developer, and this is "how I feel about this", not official statement of any kind.

Comment: As I understand Marketing list can be dynamic.